# Flex container with divs children not stacking horizontally

Tags: css, flexbox, horizontallist

I'm fairly new to flexbox, and can't figure out how to do what I'm trying.  I'd like for the repeated content to stack horizontally to the right.  I would like the items to shrink to fit the width of the content (if the title/report id text is longer/shorter). I'm trying to make the red box only as wide as the content and stack to the right.  The purple box(container) is flex.  It seems like the red div is the culprit that I can't figure out.  I've tried converting to inline-block and played with the flex-grow and flex-shrink, but nothing seems to work for me. There might be a style somewhere else in the project that is competing, but not sure what to look for if that's the case...
[image]

Styles of the purple container div:

```
line-height: 1.5;
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
max-height: 22.8125rem;
padding-bottom: .5rem;
margin-bottom: 1rem;
background-color: #394b54;
flex-basis: 100%;
-webkit-box-flex: 1;
flex-grow: 1;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'd like for the repeated content to stack horizontally to the right

Use the default `flex-direction: row`.

> I would like the items to shrink to fit the width of the content

Use the default `flex-grow: 0` and `flex-basis: content`.

Comment: works, thank you!  I was thinking the content would be stacked as columns, not the container itself was flexing as a row.